# Format Interger with two decimal format in UITextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I am presenting the user with a field that displays the number keyboard and only want them to be able to enter numbers with decimal it should be only one. After decimal it is should be atleast 2 digits will be there. There should be atleast one digit before the decimal.Then the input can`t be 0 or 0.00. Suppose if user enter the number 123456 it is accepted then 123.56 it also accepted if user enter 123 and then it it take 000123 and how can i take maximum length of the textfield is 6 and minimum is 1 please help me this one...

Thanks in advance

Comment: where you want to check this when you press some done button or you want that when user enters 6 digits he cannot be able to enter more digits.

Comment: if user enter 25  it will take 000025 not more than 6 digits suppose if user enters 1 it will take 000001 like that after 3 or 4 characters . should be appear it also calculate as one number..please help me this one...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format Interger with two decimal format in UITextfield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185092/format-interger-with-two-decimal-format-in-uitextfield)

Answer (score 0):

check with this condition and add prefix

```
 NSLog(@"%d",[textfield.text length]);                 
  if(length<0)
  {
   add prefix for remaining;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a logic for you.You can use this:;-

```
NSString *string=yourtextField.text;//it will contain your text field text
    int stringLength=[string length];
    if (stringLength>6) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
    else if(stringLength>1)
    {
        int n=6-stringLength;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            NSString *newString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%@",string];
            string=newString;
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"empty string");
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes it is working but if user enter one letter it is not taking the zero`s.Then i want only one decimal before the 2 digits decimal should must please help me for this one...

Comment: if you enter 1 it will print like 000001.Am i right this was your problem.

Comment: please elaborate what you want to do with decimals

Comment: It is not printing 000001 it will print only 1 if the user enter the amount 150.86 it will take the valve if the user enter 15.506 it will not take the valve after decimal exactly 2 digits must be there please help me this one...

Comment: i got the answer of 000001 but in this textfield decimal will use one time only how can we give this one please help me this one...